# Android Wear App java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

Tags: java, android, gps, location, wear-os

I had a problem. I want to make an Android App for my Android Wear device. I want to get the latitude and longitude of my current location. But when I run the applicatie I got this error:

```
03-22 11:14:00.096 29013-29013/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 52435096 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                                                   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                                                   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                                                   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                                                   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                                                   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                                                   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                                                   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                                                   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                                                   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:687)
                                                   at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:198)
                                                   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                                                   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                                                   at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
                                                   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvHuidigeLocatie;
private Button btSetHuidigeLocatie;

GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {


            onClickInfoButtonListener();
        }
    });
}

private void onClickInfoButtonListener() {
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    tvHuidigeLocatie = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.tvHuidigeLocatie);
    btSetHuidigeLocatie = (Button) stub.findViewById(R.id.btnSetHuidigeLocatie);
    btSetHuidigeLocatie.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                        tvHuidigeLocatie.setText("" + latitude + ", " + longitude);
                    }else{
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

**GPSTracker.java**

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context context;

boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;

double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return location;
                }

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation(){
    return this.canGetLocation();
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS in settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS staat niet aan, Wilt u naar uw instellingen gaan?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Instellingen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Annuleer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

I hope anyone see the problem and can help me with this problem.

Comment: Please be a little more particular about where exactly this problem is occuring

Comment: Sorry! When I clicked on the button btSetHuidigeLocatie then Android Studio give this problem in the log.

Comment: Use the debugger to keep stepping till this shows up, after button press. That will be the problem line. It will help us find the issue.

Comment: The stacktrace isnt complete, or is it that at no point does ANY of the stacktrace lines mention one of your classes? We need to know which line in which file that you wrote the error occured.

Comment: Most likely your app is leaking memory somewhere (especially considering this is still happening when you follow the bad `largeHeap="true"` advice). And it's highly unlikely that anyone here will spot a memory leak just from looking at your source code. Learn about monitoring memory use at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html, and do so while stepping through your app to narrow down where the leak is occurring.

Answer (score -1):

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

In your android manifest, hope this will solve your problem.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Comment: Might work on a few devices, but not the best style, no? `Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.`

Comment: I also add this, but it doesn't help.

Comment: yes this is not very good way to resolved OOM but this is very quick option to that, else it is must that you need to reduced the memory consumption in the device.

Comment: Precisely. This, I feel, can go as a comment, not as an answer. Since its a pretty (terrible) hack, and can promote bad practice.

Comment: @DebosmitRay I agree with you that this is bad practice but at the same time you have to consider that, this option is given by Android itself, and it would be great if you have given him some tips about how to apply good practice after looking at the code would help him to resolved this issue. My primary goal is to resolved issue and on the link if you go and read it then it is clearly mention that you have to reduced the use of memory.